# Multiple return types in MyBatis?

Tags: java, orm, mybatis

I have two classes A and B with many fields each, and one table with values for all those fields.  I have tried unsuccessfully to craft `<select>` and `<resultMap>` elements that would return a list of pairs of objects of types A and B.

The only (not so clean) solution I have found so far is to just implement a `typeHandler` associated to one column (say, the first of the table) and in that code create the two objects I need by reading all columns from the `ResultSet` passed to the type handler rather than just the column name passed as a `String` to the type handler.

Is there a cleaner solution using result maps?  (Note: I don't want to partition my table to match the two object types).

Comment: Just to make that clear... You want to get a List<Pair<A,B>>, with one Pair for each row? In that case, your resultType should be the pair and I don't see the problem here. Never tried it, but you should be able to access the Pair's property in the resultMap.

Comment: Yes, that's the result type I want. It's not a problem to construct a Pair in the resultMap. The problem is that I can only assign one column as argument for A and one column for B. But what I need is to pass multiple, different columns to the constructor of A and B.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Achieving your purpose can be done by using associations: Check the documentation for [Nested Results for Association](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html)

```
<resultMap id="pairResultMap" type="Pair">
    <association property="a"  resultMap="aResultMap" />
    <association property="b" javaType="B">
        <!-- define mapping here -->
    </association> 
</resultMap>
<resultMap id="aResultMap" type="A">            
    <!-- define mapping here -->
</resultMap>
```

You may either directly define the "sub" result map (B) or reference it (A).